# Disable or get around Adobe AIR sandbox in the HTMLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I often hit this problem, I need to use htmlloader and load a page and the page uses some library or script that conflicts with the sandbox. I used other frameworks(Qt4,.NET ,Java) and never had to face such restrictions.
I was unable to find a way to disable the sandbox, I read the documentation about bridges and sanbox types but I did not understand the concepts, is it possible to use that sandbox bridges or anything else (maybe whitelist domains and/or local scripts)
As an example try loading this page

```
var url:String="http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=wordpress%20plugins";
htmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
htmlLoader.width=stage.width;
htmlLoader.height=stage.height;
stage.addChild(htmlLoader);
```

Any sugestions are welcome, links to examples.

P.S. In other place I hit this limitation is when I try to load a local html that uses some local scripts/library, fixing the library to work with AIR is not a solution.
I can't restart and use other framework since I am adding some features to some large applications(porting is not a solution).

Thanks.

Comment: The security sandbox is there for security purposes.  It cannot be disabled.  What type of conflicts are you running into?  What is the behavior you expect and what is the behavior you see?  If you're just having trouble loading pages; you may have to run them through a server side proxy.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com , I understand is for security of the user, but it should be able to disable it, like the user can allow using the webcam or microphone I want to load any webpage without the sandbox blocking some Javascript(like eval and other stuf) , try loading the page in my example and see how it looks in AIR and how it looks in a normal browser. I assume I can't disable it but how can I work around it(whitelist a domain or some local file somehow?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to get around things put in place to prevent cross-site scripting.  The solution is to create a server side proxy and run all your URLs through that.  It is best to provide a runnable sample if you want people to test your code.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I am building a desktop application,I understand the security is there for flash content on browsers but a desktop application is different,is signed and must be installed by the user, also in one of my apps I use html and javascript stored localy in the assetsso I do not even need internet,  I use javascript and html because Flex is missing some components like Rich html editor, I do not see any valid reason why a desktop application should have this limitations

Comment: Flex has a Rich Text Editor; although it is not as full featured as the many HTML Variants out there. All desktop applications exist in a sandbox.  AIR just gives you a slightly "expanded" sandbox when compared to a browser app. I've never compared it to access you get when developing for Java or .NET, though.  I think now is a good time to re-iterate my original question: "What type of conflicts are you running into? What is the behavior you expect and what is the behavior you see"

Comment: @www.Flextras.com  OK,expected result is that html pages should work , what I see are page not p[roperly working, sometimes script errors.

Comment: Please quantify what "not properly working" means.  Runtime errors?  Compiler errors?  Are you getting unexpected behavior?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Here is what I get when trying to load the page in the sample code ,  http://imagebin.org/251006  I do not get any runtime errors or debug messages, but this is not the only problem I have, in other application I want to load a page with latest ckeditor(the editor files are stored in assets on disk) and there I can see in the console output errors at runtime about the sandbox, do you know about bridge sandbox? can that be used? I am just wondering if maybe I did not understand those sandboxes, maybe they considered this limitations and let us a way around them on desktop

Comment: It should be possible to edit your question and add that image as part of it.  It helps to clarify the exact issue you're facing.  The solution is out of my realm of knowledge; but hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: 2015 and I'm having this problem.
Inline images don't work in AIR in the TextField.